# Keep constant reference to return value of function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, return-value

If I keep a constant reference to a non-reference returned value of a function in C++11, where does the reference point in the stack? And is it safe to do so?

```
string foo() {
  std::string foo_ret = "foo string";
  return foo_ret;
}

int main() {
  const std::string& a = foo();
}
```

Comment: its safe. temporary lifetime is extended because its bind to reference. (might want const reference though)

Comment: It doesn't compile: `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'`

Comment: @tp1 this is not safe and won't even compile

Comment: "If I keep a reference of a non-reference" – unfortunately you can't do that. It is not valid C++.

Comment: he's just missing const. Once you add that, it magically becomes valid c++.

Comment: @tp1 Are you sure? Maybe he wants an rvalue reference and is just missing another `&`? Or maybe he really wants a non-const lvalue reference and his compiler is silently allowing him to do that, which made him think it's possible?

Comment: @melpomene thanks, I've added `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is illegal; non-const lvalue references may not bind to rvalues. There's not really a *good* reason behind this, it's just a language rule that was introduced very early on in C++'s history.
 <sub>MSVC used to (maybe still does) allow this binding, I can't comment on how MSVC implements it.</sub>

You can bind to other reference types though:

```
std::string const &a = foo();   // (1)
std::string&& b = foo();        // (2)
```

In case (2), `b` binds directly to the return value object, which has its lifetime extended to match `b`'s lifetime.  Note: no "move" operation occurs here, it is just binding a reference.

In case (1), conceptually, a temporary of type `const std::string` is initialized from the return value, and that temporary has its lifetime extended to match `a`'s lifetime.  In practice this copy will be [elided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization). your code will behave as if the reference bound directly to the return value.

---

Generally speaking, you should use value semantics. `std::string c = foo();` is the safest option. Because of copy elision, it is not any less efficient than the reference options.

The main danger with the reference option is that if the function were changed to return a reference, then `a` or `b` may become a dangling reference.

Comment: I've meant `const &`. So, in case (1) where the data is stored? heap or stack?

Comment: @ebi implementation-defined. It will probably pair up with NRVO, and construct the returned string directly inside `main()`'s stackframe.

Comment: "(and maybe even more efficient)" – Could you add a "why" there?

Comment: @ebi it could be stored anywhere, so long as the object continues to exist so long as `a` exists. The usual thing to do is that the object is in the stack area of the function containing `a`.

Comment: @zenith not really, it would be just hand-waving, so I've removed that comment

Answer (score 0):

No it is not safe to do so, and it is an error and will not compile.

You might be looking for R Value references: http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html

Comment: It's neither safe nor unsafe. It doesn't compile.

Comment: as melpomene said this is not safe and won't compile.  it does not matter what version of C++ you are using: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63d530bedf9d1b7f

Comment: You should also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object

Comment: Why would it be overwritten by function calls? `foo()` doesn't return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @melpomene, hmm, I must have been using a dodgy compiler years ago when I had to debug problems caused by this. It doesn't compile now.

Comment: Your answer is still not correct.  This code won't even compile as is so nothing will be overwritten as it will never run.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the statement was if it  was allowed. I've clarified it.

Comment: @melpomene, the variable would be on the stack, which would likely be overwritten if it was allowed.

Comment: @melpomene, I think I understand now. The temporary would be put on the stack of the calling function, so any new function call would be called above/below it, not overwriting it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is legal to to do.

When you return a `string` from the function, it returns a `Rvalue` or temporary object. You can not use normal `Lvalue` reference to fetch the `Rvalue` but you can use const `Lvalue` reference to fetch. When you use const `Lvalue` reference, the life time of the temporary object is extended to be the same as the reference does.

As for where the reference point to in the memory, I guess it may vary by implementation. But what matters here is that the temporary object is no longer 'temporary', although you can not change it.